# Etale cohomology of pushforward on affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-cohomology

Let $X = Spec(\mathcal O_K)$ be the spectrum of the ring of integers of a number field $K$. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a non-zero prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ and let $i: Spec(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p) \to X$ be the inclusion map.
Let $\mathbb Z$ be the constant sheaf on $Spec(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p)$. Apparently, we have
$$H^1(X_{et}, i_* \mathbb Z) = H^1(Spec(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p)_{et}, \mathbb Z).$$
Could somebody please give me a hint or a reference for why this is true? Thank you.

Comment: I'm farily sure that the RHS is always zero. Not quite sure about the LHS

Comment: This follows because $i$ is a closed embedding, and finite maps are acyclic for the etale topology: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03QP

Also, @LukasHeger is right. One easy way to see this in this case is to note that by this: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424102/relationship-between-galois-cohomology-and-etale-cohomology/1424117#1424117

the right-hand side is isomorphic to $H^1_\text{cont.}(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k),\mathbf{Z})$ where $k:=\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ and where $\mathbf{Z}$ has the trivial action.

Comment: But this is just $\text{Hom}_\text{cont.}(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k),\mathbf{Z})$ which is trivial as any such homomorphism must factorize through a finite quotient: this is true as $\mathbf{Z}$ is discrete, $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ is not and has a basis of finite index open normal subgroups, and $\mathbf{Z}$ is torsion free.

Comment: @AlexYoucis you're of course correct, here's an alternative high-level way to see this. If $X$ is a scheme and $A$ is any abelian group, then we have an isomorphism $H^1_{ét}(X,A) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1^{ét}(X),A)$, where $\pi_1^{ét}$ denotes the (gros) étale progroup from SGA 3. But for $X$ locally noetherian and geometrically unibranch, one gets that the SGA3-fundamental progroup is the same as the SGA1-fundamental group, which is profinite, hence for any locally noetherian geometrically unibranch scheme $X$, we get $H^1_{ét}(X,\Bbb Z)=0$.

Comment: @LukasHeger That is correct. By the way, you only require that $X$ is locally topologically Noetherian, not necessarily Noetherian (e.g. a finite type scheme over $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{C}_p}$ would also work).